# moving rails2 to 5 and getting error - undefined method `with_scope'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

How to replace this query in rails 5.0.6

```
with_scope(:create => {:article_id => article_id, :created_at => 
created_at}) do
    yield
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3051-Chaining-ActiveRecord-Relation-Methods-in-Rails-5) covers how to implement without the with_scope that was removed in Rails 4. Also there is a new syntax introduced in Rails 4, if I remember correctly, so your code would have looked like this if 'with_scope' was working.

```
with_scope(create: { article_id: article_id, created_at: created_at }) do
  yield
end
```